# PHP: many if conditions compare

Tags: php, if-statement, compare

I have to check if "id" is around 15 different values....

```
if($value->id==1 or $value->id==2 or $value->id==3 or $value->id==4 etc etc....)
```

what is the better/shorter way to do that....

Comment: `in_array` for example

Comment: If your question is a correct representation of the problem you can do `if($id >0 && $id <16)`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use an array and the [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) method:

```
$acceptableValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

if (in_array($value->id, $acceptableValues)) {

}
```

You can always force a strict validation by specifying the third parameter as true, meaning the values will need to be identical in value and type:

```
$acceptableValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

if (in_array((int) $value->id, $acceptableValues, true)) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have two option for check multiple conditions

## 1

```
echo in_array($var, array('abc', 'def', 'hij', 'klm', 'nop'))? 'yes': 'no';
```

## 2

```
 $test_array = ('test1','test2', 'test3','test4');
    for($i = 0; $i < count($test_array); $i++){
       if($test_value == $test_array[$i]){
           $ret_val = true;
           break;
       }
       else{
           $ret_val = false;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Save that values in a separate array and check

```
if( in_array($value->id, $idArray)
```